# ObjectContext.Translate: avoiding column-mapping mistakes

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've started porting old ADO.NET code to Linq to Entities.  One particularly useful function is [`ObjectContext.Translate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487244.aspx) and its companion [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487195.aspx) which allow you to use arbitrary SQL and unwrap them into plain old data objects.

However, it's easy to make mistakes in the column mapping: a mispelled column name or differing case causes a .NET property no longer to match the intended SQL column.  This is particularly tricky to detect when the DB schema changes.  When a .NET property doesn't correspond to an sql column, no exception is thrown - instead, Linq to entities just [sets the property to the default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx#sectionSection0) (`null`, `0`, etc.).  This behavior might be occasionally useful, allowing types to contain extra properties, but it's also very good at hiding bugs, particularly when `null` or the default value is a valid value for that column.

Is there any way to change this behavior or at least detect when its occuring so that such mistakes are immediately obvious?

In other words: can I enforce that the shape of the .NET object must exactly match the shape of the SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot enforce it but you can write set of integration tests which will automatically verify that your classes still have the correct shape.

Comment: Right, but that's rather unhandy since it requires manually duplicating all that nice logic the entity framework provides to map columns to properties; or, worse to actually _manually_ write a test for each and every query seperately essentially just to verify absence of such a trivial error.

Comment: Yes you must manually write those tests because you are using manually written queries - that is not something EF can handle for you. Integration tests are exactly what people use to verify hand written queries. If you don't like it start using LINQ-to-entities instead to avoid these errors at all.

Comment: It's not necessary: I've added a verification step in my code.  It simply checks whether all columns in the DataReader correspond to a property of the given type and vice-versa.  Then it's just a matter of listing the relevant queries (which in my case is again possible with reflection) and having just 1 simple test trying them.  It's much more complex than just letting the EF do this verification for you, but still much simpler than maintaining yet another boilerplate representation of my data's structure.

Comment: So put it as an answer. It can help others.

Comment: Translate completely fails for Table Per Hierarchy types, so it's useless anyway.